# Ipad Mini 2 Warranty for Damage

Tags: ipad, applecare

I bought my daughter her ipad for Christmas (7 months ago) and she dropped it the other day cracking the screen; you can actually see inside of it at the top.

Does this come with a manufacture warranty and will it cover accidental damage?

Comment: Is that the same with the Ipads I have no idea about anything with the pads and phone no a days.

Answer (score 1):

AppleCare does not cover damage.  However, [AppleCare+](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/S4575LL/A/applecare-for-iphone) covers up to two incidents of damage:

> AppleCare+ for iPhone Every iPhone comes with one year of hardware
>   repair coverage through its limited warranty and up to 90 days of
>   complimentary support. AppleCare+ for iPhone extends your coverage to
>   two years from the original purchase date of your iPhone(1) and adds
>   up to two incidents of accidental damage coverage, each subject to a
>   service fee plus applicable tax ($79 for iPhone SE or iPhone 6 or
>   earlier models, $99 for iPhone 6s or iPhone 6s Plus).

So, if you don't have an AppleCare+ agreement, you will have to cover the damages out of pocket.